# UICollectionView update size asyncly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am implementing a app with Pinterest-style 2 column layout. And want each cell's size to be dynamic corresponds to the image's size.

I use SDWebImage to asyncly load the image to the cell and then invalidate collectionView's layout. However since cells are reusable and thus everytime the screen scrolls up & down, the layout will get invalidated and some unwanted animation is produced.

Here's my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

    cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imageUrl, completed: { (image, error, _, _) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        })
    })
    return cell
}
```

Cell size function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGSize {

    var width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 2 - 3
    // create a cell size from the image size, and return the size
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CraveCollectionViewCell{

        if cell.imageView.image != nil {

            let image = cell.imageView.image!
            var height = image.size.height * width / image.size.width
            let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
            var height1 = size.height > 160 ? size.height : 160
            return CGSize(width: width, height: height1)

        }
    }
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 160)
}
```

}

When the images gets load first by SDWebImage, `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` is called and the layout works fine.

After scolling, `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`
 is called again and here is where the problem comes.

Comment: you r adding this animation : animateWithDuration, can u do without animation and check

Comment: @Swati thanks for your comment. The layout was still invalidated everytime  during scrolling, can still see some jerkness going on. I want to find a way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Originally my cell size was calculated by image after SDWebImage get it, which is async and was the cause of the jerkness.

So to solve it, server should return the size of image first, so that the cell size was not calculated asyncly.